# Capturing and storing all matches for regex using D

Tags: regex, d

I'm trying to capture every instance of text consisting of letters, numbers and the underscore following a % symbol, as long as it's not %% or an escaped %. I wrote the following regex to do it:

`((?<!(?:\\|%))%[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`

I want to store everything it captures in this manner into an associative array, and so I wrote the following function to do it:

```
string[string] make_symbol_table(string input) {
  string[string] symbol_table;
  auto m = matchAll(input, regex(r"((?<!(?:\\|%))%[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", "g")).captures();
  for (auto i = 1; i < m.length; i++) {
    symbol_table[m[i]] = null;
  }
  return symbol_table;
}
```

And tested it on the following input:

`This is an ordinary %template, with a few well-situated %template_arguments. It uses a range of characters, mostly to ensure that %template1 works correctly.\n\nYou can even start %1template with a number! We can also have some silly cases: %_ %1, %a, and so on. %%DIRECTIVES should never be captured, nor should escaped \\% or \\%\\%. %CAPS or %CaPs are fine too.`

which I've written as an escaped string. I assume that this will give me 9 matches (confirmed by [this](http://regex101.com/r/pS9tI3/1#python)), but for some reason, I only get 1! Am I using `matchAll` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.captures` is the same as `.front`, i.e. the first match. You're interested in all matches. So drop `.captures`.

Then, `m` is a `RegexMatch` which doesn't have `.length`. Just `foreach` over it: `foreach(match; m)`.

`match` is a `Captures`, i.e. a range of the full match and all the submatches. You're interested in the full match*. So use `match.front` or `match[0]` to get the string: `symbol_table[match.front] = null;`

* or the first submatch - they're the same, because the whole thing is parenthesized

---

Maybe this can help clear things up a bit:

- `matchAll(...)` returns a range of matches:

  - 1st match is a range of the full match and the submatches:

    - full match: "%template"
    - 1st submatch: "%template"
  - 2nd match ditto:

    - full match: "%template_arguments"
    - 1st submatch: "%template_arguments"
  - 3rd match ditto:

    - full match: "%template1"
    - 1st submatch: "%template1"
  - ...